# Why is my Server TcpListener Working with Local Address but not with Public Address? - Exception: The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, tcplistener, socketexception

I wrote a server and a client program in C# using a TcpListener and a TcpClient and I want them to exchange a string. It works if both PCs are connected to the same network and if I use the local address of the server, but when the PCs are connected to a different network and I use a public address it gives me the following error:

```
Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in its context
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()
   at Server___Network_Class.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Server - Network Class\Program.cs:line 18
```

This error refers to line 18, which is myList.Start(); but I don't know why it throws this exception. I opened my router port and I set up correctly the Windows Firewall...
Here's the Server and Client code I wrote:

**Server**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server___Network_Class {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("146.241.31.193"); //That's the public IP

                //Initialize the listener
                TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 51328);
                //Start listening the selected port
                myList.Start();

                
                Socket socket = myList.AcceptSocket();

                
                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                socket.Send(asen.GetBytes("Can you read this?"));

                
                socket.Close();
                myList.Stop();

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e);

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Client___Class_Network {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                //Inizializzo il client
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

                //Cerco di connettermi al server
                client.Connect("146.241.31.193", 51328); //IP and Port i want to connect to
                
                //Stream sul quale inviare e ricevere i dati dal server
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                Byte[] bytesRecived = new Byte[256];
                int totBytesRecived = stream.Read(bytesRecived, 0, bytesRecived.Length);
                String stringData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesRecived, 0, totBytesRecived);


                Console.Write(stringData);

                client.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Only the server program throws that exception, the client one seems working file...

Could you please help me out with this problem? I have (almost) searched all over the web but I couldn't find any useful answer.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the public IP address really available at your Windows machine or only on the router?

Check if the public address shows up when running `ipconfig` in the Command line window. My guess is that you need to set up NAT port forwarding in the router and set the application to listen to the IP address your router gave to your Windows machine. Such an IP address typically starts with `10.` or `192.`.

Try binding your server to the address `0.0.0.0`. This way, it will listen to all your network cards (WiFi, Ethernet) without the need for any configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. I don't know why but the IP address that the website [whatismyipaddress.com](https://whatismyipaddress.com) gave me was incorrect. In the client program I entered the IP that i found on my router's configuration page (it was a different one) and it worked.

Comment: I am sure that whatismyipaddress is right, too. It is your external IP. That is relevant if a TCP client wants to your server from the outside.

Comment: No where's another problem... Yesterday I tried to connect with a friend that has the same ISP, and it was able to communicate with me. But I called another friends that has a different ISP and he wasn't able to connect to my server... Isn't that strange? Do you know why?

Comment: This may be due to a port limitation on their side. My instinct is that it is not the difference in ISPs or your application. Maybe use a more standard port instead of 51328. If you can an exception when starting your server, it's probably because the port is taken by something on your computer. Don't use port 80 because the Windows kernel often holds it. Good luck!